# Google Analytics - How to track logged in user's ID when they submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

The website has a registration form, and when the user submits their personal details it creates an account for them and the page is reloaded for them to continue with additional form fields. At this point we have a user ID for them from our own users database table.

How can we track this in Google Analytics, to say that user (ID 12345 according to our database) has registered?

- The form is just a standard submit to the same PHP script (no ajax, no separate page after submit).

It has been a couple of years since I used GA (when it was ga.js) other than just adding the tracking code. How do I achieve this in the current Universal Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you do it like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', { 'userId': 12345 });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

(Remember to replace `UA-XXXXX-Y` with your own Tracking ID.)

[**How to set up User ID**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#user_id)

[**General information about the User ID feature**](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en)

Comment: But the user ID is not known until the form submit has been made and the page reloads.

Comment: @BadHorsie which means it isn't possible to register the User ID before the page reloads :) Register it after.

Comment: "User ID enables the analysis of groups of sessions, across devices, using a unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable ID string representing a user. "  this information is stored in the background.  he wont be able to see it in anyway Userid is an internal value only.

Comment: I think this is for the GA's internal user ID it uses for tracking. I am trying to track the user system of the website's user ID, only on this event that they submitted this particular form.

Comment: @BadHorsie I am confused. What is the expected result here? Do you want to be able to look up users by their ID via the GA reporting interface?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Well actually it's not me who will be doing it, I have just been requested to track some sort of event that can be seen in GA that website user 12345 (according to the users table in our own database) registered. Perhaps later we will be tasked with tracking more events that user 12345 has done something else.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Sorry, I have actually just read in more depth the articles you have linked. I believe this may be the correct answer. I will implement it and see if it works. The only thing I'm not sure about is how to see the information in GA in the correct way. Is it possible to see statistics of how many users are registering, when it happened, and which users did it?

Comment: @BadHorsie yes, all of this should be possible. See this article: http://www.mugo.ca/Blog/Tracking-individual-users-in-Google-Analytics — tell me if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with [Custom Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) using Google Analytics.

```
if((typeof ga == 'function')) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Register', 'user', 'User ID', <?php echo $user->id; ?>, {
       nonInteraction: true
    });
}
```

In your case, you want to make sure it only fires off when the page is being submitted:

```
<?php if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')): ?>
    if((typeof ga == 'function')) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Register', 'user', 'User ID', <?php echo $user->id; ?>, {
           nonInteraction: true
        });
    }
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can put this anywhere in the page after the point where you've initialized your GA.

Comment: But where/when do I put this? I don't want it to trigger every time they refresh the page. It should happen the first and only time they submit the form with 100% success.

Comment: good idea. try this as well https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Other things I'm unsure about with this is how do I know that GA has been loaded? I can see multiple potential problems with this, such as GA is blocked by the user's browser (adblock) which would cause an error; that the GA script has not been loaded fully yet, etc.

Comment: @DaImTo Isn't this basically the same approach? It just registers the User ID, isn't it? Or will this have a different result compared to my approach?

Comment: @BadHorsie I've updated the answer according to your use-case.

Comment: I normally put user id in a custom dimension.   It's a little different than loging it as an event